# Calculation of work to create a vaccum

Tags: energy, vacuum-pumps

I am trying to calculate the work required to lower the pressure in a box from P1 = 1 bar to P2 = 0.1 bar. The box has volume V. Is this simply VdP work? If not, how do I perform an energy analysis to solve this? The temperature in the box at the start of the process is T1.

Comment: looks like schoolwork ... please show your work ... add it to the post ... do **not** add a comment